# Compare Items in the "IN" Clause and the resultset

Tags: sql, oracle

I'd like to achieve something as follows, I have the following query (As simple as this),

```
SELECT ENT_ID,TP_ID FROM TC_LOGS WHERE ENT_ID IN (1,2,3,4,5).
```

Now the table `TC_LOGS` may not have all the items in the IN clause. So assuming that the table `TC_LOGS` has only 1,2. I'd like to compare the items in the IN clause i.e. 1,2,3,4,5 with 1,2(the resultset) and get a result as FOUND - 1,2 NOT FOUND - 3,4,5. I've have implemented this by applying an XSL transformation on the resultset in the application code, but I'd like to achieve this in a query, which I feel is more of an elegant solution to this problem. Also, I tried the following query with `NVL`, just to separate out the FOUND and NOT FOUND items as,

```
SELECT NVL(ENT_ID,"NOT FOUND") FROM TC_LOGS WHERE ENT_ID IN(1,2,3,4,5)
```

I was expecting a result as 1,2,NOT FOUND,NOT FOUND,NOT FOUND

But the above query doesn't return any result.. I'd appreciate if someone can guide me in the right path here.. Thanks much in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that the items in your `IN` list can (or can come) from another query, you can do something like

```
WITH src AS (
  SELECT level id
    FROM dual
 CONNECT BY level <= 5)
SELECT nvl(ent_id, 'Not Found' )
  FROM src
       LEFT OUTER JOIN tc_logs ON (src.id = tc_logs.ent_id)
```

In my case, the `src` query is just generating the numbers 1 through 5.  You could just as easily fetch that data from a different table, load the numbers into a collection that you query using the `TABLE` operator, load the numbers into a temporary table that you query, etc. depending on how the `IN` list data is determined.

Answer (score 0):

NVL isn't going to work because no values (including NULLS) are returned when there is no match with the IN statement.

What you can do is something like this:

```
SELECT NVL(ENT_ID, "NOT FOUND") 
FROM TC_LOGS
RIGHT OUTER JOIN (
   SELECT 1 AS 'TempID' UNION 
   SELECT 2 UNION 
   SELECT 3 UNION
   SELECT 4 UNION 
   SELECT 5) AS Sub ON ENT_ID = TempID
```

The outer join will return NULLS for ENT_ID where there are no matches.  Note, I'm not an Oracle person so I can't guarantee that this syntax is perfect.

Comment: Thanks very much for all the responses. I believe the response from Justin should work, if only I figure out how to feed the items in the IN clause. In the meantime I figured out a solution. I am querying for the IN clause items from dual and doing a "MINUS" with my query from my post..

Answer (score 0):

if you have a table (let's use table src )contains all (1,2,3,4,5) values, you can use full join.
You can use (WITH src AS (     SELECT level id       FROM dual    CONNECT BY level <= 5)  as the src table also)

```
         SELECT 
           ent_id,tl.tp_id,src.tp_id 
         FROM 
           src
        FULL JOIN
          tc_logs tl
        USING (ent_id)
        ORDER BY
          ent_id
```

Here is the web site for oracle full join.http://psoug.org/snippet/Oracle-PL-SQL-ANSI-Joins-FULL-JOIN_738.htm